# Is flashing an OpenGApps package over Cyanogen secure?

Tags: android

I wanted to flash CyanogenMod onto my cellphone, but noticed this requires also flashing a package from opengapps.org. I know Google Apps are signed by keys but how secure is flashing one of these packages? Am I opening myself up to Malware by installing this? Due to the apps being closed source, there's no way to inspect these files myself that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

> Due to the apps being closed source, there's no way to inspect these files myself that I am aware of.

I'm pretty sure that you did not inspect Cyanogenmod source code or checked if the provided ROM for your platform matches the source code available. You've probably also did not check the firmware of the device which is usually only available as binary too and [is actually the source of security problems](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/quadrooter-qualcomm-android-firmware-vulnerabilities,32414.html).

This means that downloading GApps from a widely published source is probably as risky as what you did before. Yes, these files could contain malware but the chance is low since lots of others use these files and did not notice anything more malicious than the expected privacy problems with these apps. But of course someone could have recently compromised the download server and exchanged the downloads like done [in case of other trusted sources](http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=2994).

But at the end you should trust your device only as much as you trust all parties which were involved in building and distributing it. This not only includes custom ROM's and apps but but also hardware (which is not this hard anymore, i.e. often software too). And this is not only true for your phone but also for your computer, router, internet provider, car ...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Steffen's answer: the downloads from OpenGApps.org are signed. Using JDK keytool you can inspect the certificate that has been used to sign the zip.